# How to Send Data with POST Requests in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, api, ionic2, google-fusion-tables, http-status-code-401

I have created an app using `Google API` and I'm using `Google fusion tables` for the backend so I have enabled the `fusion table API` as well. I'm making an hybrid app using `ionic 2`. `GET` works perfectly for reading the table and `POST` given an 
`error 401`

.

```js
function submitAnswer(button) {
    
    var accessToken = document.getElementById("accessToken").value;
 var query = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=INSERT INTO " + answerTableId + "(Answers,QuestionId,UserID) VALUES ('" + button.value + "','" + currentQueNo + "','" + userId + "')"+key+"&access_token="+accessToken;
 
 var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
     //alert(this.readyState + " " + this.status);
     if(this.readyState == 4) {
      alert(this.responseText);

     }
    };
    xhttp2.open("POST", query, true);
    xhttp2.setRequestHeader('Authorization',accessToken);
    xhttp2.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've only forgotten "Bearer " in your Authorization value :

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oauthToken.access_token);
```

Or maybe you've just badly encoded your accessToken in your query (you need to use encodeURIComponent(accessToken))

If this is called from a browser and not from NodeJS, you may be blocked by CORS issue.

Also, not related to your question : your way of creating the request is very sensible to SQL injection. Some random user could just delete your whole database without knowing any password.

Comment: Thankyou so much, guess "bearer" was the part missing that did the trick for me. Also I had missed a letter while using the API key.

Answer (score 0):

Sincw you are using ionic 2 while don't create like an interceptor that extends the main angular `http` like this code sample below should do every trick for you and i suggest you adhere to it. Since it is ionic 2 angular 2+

Firstly, create a class to extend the **http** class like so `api-handler.ts`:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { environment } from './environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

/*
  Generated class for the ApiHandler provider.

  this is used to make communication with our endpoint where we pass endpoint 
  header information and any form of manipulation
*/
@Injectable()
export class ApiHandler extends Http {
  private bearer: string = 'Plutus';

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _storage: Storage) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  /**
    * This is used to call our api service by inputing the service url
    * @param service_url 
    * @param method  
    * @param params 
    * @param options 
    * 
    * @return Observable<any>
    */
  callService(service_url: string, method: RequestMethod, params?: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {

    if (params == null) {
      params = {};
    }

    options = this.requestOptions(method, params, options);


    let token_promise: Promise<any> = this._storage.get('token');

    return Observable.fromPromise(token_promise)
      .mergeMap(token => {
        console.log("token from storage", token);
        if (options.headers == null && token != null) {
          options.headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': `${this.bearer} ${token}`
          });
        }

        return super.request(this.getFullUrl(service_url), options)
          .catch(this.onCatch);
      });
  }


  /**
   * Request options is used to manipulate and handle needed information before
   * it is sent to server
   * @param options
   * @returns {RequestOptionsArgs}
   */
  private requestOptions(method: RequestMethod, params: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
    if (options == null) {
      options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    options.method = method;

    if (options.method === RequestMethod.Post || options.method === RequestMethod.Put) {
      options.body = params;
    } else {
      options.params = params;
    }

    return options;
  }

  /**
   * Build API url.
   * and we remove any leading / from the service calls since 
   * we are not needing then in making request calls
   * e.g localhost:1337//base... to localhost:1337/base..
   * @param url
   * @returns {string}
   */
  private getFullUrl(url: string): string {
    if (url.charAt(0) == "/") {
      url = url.substring(1);
    }
    return environment.endpoint + url;
  }


  /**
     * Error handler.
     * @param error
     * @param caught
     * @returns {ErrorObservable}
     */
  private onCatch(error: any, caught: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.throw(x);
  }

}
```

if you observe the way i added header information on the above code and using the request method which allows for any form of http methods like Request.Get, Request.Post, Request.Put, Request.Delete, etc.

Secondly, in your **app.module.ts** provide the class as your default http call for any backend communication by adding the below to your **providers**:[]

```
{
      provide: ApiHandler,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, _storage: Storage) => new ApiHandler(backend, defaultOptions, _storage),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Storage]
    }
```

Then finally, to use it in your case just add this to your constructor, then use straight away like this

```
import { IFeedBack } from './../interfaces/ifeedback';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ApiHandler } from './../util/api-handler';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the FeedBackServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class FeedBackService {

  constructor(private _apiHandler: ApiHandler) {
  }

  /**
   * this is used to create new feedback 
   * @param feedback 
   */
  create(feedback: IFeedBack): Observable<IFeedBack> {
    return this._apiHandler.callService('/feedback', RequestMethod.Post, feedback)
      .map(res => <IFeedBack>res.json());
  }

}
```

then you can call the create with the new param to send and then subscribe to it.

Think this should serve you better.